# Print Only Seconds for perf_counter()

Tags: python

My code is this:

```
import time
import winsound

frequency = 2500
duration = 1000

while time.perf_counter() < 5:
    print(time.perf_counter())

winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

How do we only print the seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive approach, replace your while loop with:

```
sec = 0
while time.perf_counter() < 5:
    now = max(round(time.perf_counter()), sec)
    if now > sec:
        sec = now
        print(sec)
```